# I want to plot g1 and g2 in the same PlotRange

Tags: plotting

I want to plot `g1` and `g2` in the same `PlotRange`.
I wrote the following code.
But it doesn't work.
Please help me.

```
plotArealElement[r_, phi_, dr_, dphi_] := Module[
 {g1, g2, x, y, u, v, plr},
 g1 = ParametricPlot[s {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, {s, r, r + dr}, {psi, phi, phi + 
dphi}];
 u = r {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]};
 v = r {Cos[phi + dphi], Sin[phi + dphi]};
 x = v - u;
 v = (r + dr) {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]};
 y = v - u;
 plr = Options[g1, PlotRange];
 g2 = ParametricPlot[s x + t y, {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, plr[[1]]];
 Show[g1, g2]
]
```

Comment: (1) Change `g1 = ParametricPlot[s {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, ...]`  to `g1 = ParametricPlot[s {Cos[psi], Sin[psi]}, ...]` and (2) Change `plr[[1]]` in the line `g2 = ...`  to `Evaluate@plr[[1]]`

Comment: ... or remove `plr[[1]]` from the line `g2 =...`

Comment: Thank you very much, kglr

Answer (score 1):

1. Fix a typo in definition of `g1`:

```
g1 = ParametricPlot[s {Cos[psi], Sin[psi]}, {s, r, r + dr}, {psi, phi, phi + dphi}]
```

2. Either remove `plr[[1]]` in the line defining `g2` or change it to
   `Evaluate@plr[[1]]`. Note that  in both cases `Show` gets its `PlotRange` (actually all its unspecified options) from `g1` so `PlotRange` in `g2` (whether it is `Evaluate @ plr[[1]]` or `PlotRange-> anything`) does not affect the output of `Show`.

With these changes, `plotArealElement` works as expected. For example,

```
plotArealElement[.2, Pi, .1, 2 Pi/3]
```

[image]

```
plotArealElement[.2, Pi, .1, 3 Pi/2]
```

[image]